# Couldn't install Microsoft.Build.UnGAC

Tags: c#

I downloaded Visual Studio Professional, I tried to install it but it brought a report to which read, couldn't install microsoft.Build.UnGAC

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/couldnt-install-microsoftbuildungac/1392675

Answer (score -2):

I find that i haven't D disk in my computer, meanwhile vs's default install path include D disk. So I have created D disk, and it success!

Comment: I fail to see how this can be a conclusive answer to the problem. Whether the OP has a D drive or not, or whether VS was trying to install to the D drive is pure speculation. In addition, in what world does VS try to install the D drive by default?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).